# changing the name of the path when storing it in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, path

I'm trying to save number of audios in an array and then play any of them according to the number of the array's index. I have one question:
do I need to change the path for each new element?
for example:

```
NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"audioRecording.m4a"]];
```

then each time, I record and store in this path and save the path as an element of the array.
does that means that all the elements in my array are identical? which means that I'll hear the same audio even if I changed the index of my array?

Here is the code for a better explanasion:

```
- (IBAction)AudioRecord:(id)sender {
[self.AudioRecorder record];
[self.timer invalidate];
[self.AudioProgress setHidden:YES];


NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"audioRecording.m4a"]];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:nil];

NSUserDefaults *audioDefaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[audioDefaults setURL:audioFileURL forKey:@"saveAudio"];
[audioDefaults synchronize];

NSUserDefaults *defaultsAudio=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSUserDefaults *defaultsForArrayA =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *AudioArray =[[defaultsForArrayA arrayForKey:@"myAudio"] mutableCopy];
if (!AudioArray) {
    AudioArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

NSString *Audiopath=[audioFileURL path];
[AudioArray addObject:Audiopath];
defaultsAudio=defaultsForArrayA;
[defaultsAudio setObject:AudioArray forKey:@"myAudio"];
[defaultsAudio synchronize]; }
```

and here where I try to read the elements of the array:

```
- (IBAction)PlayAudio:(id)sender {
NSUserDefaults *audioDefaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
audioArray2 =[[audioDefaults arrayForKey:@"myAudio"] mutableCopy];
audioPath=[audioArray2 objectAtIndex:index];
loadAudio= [NSURL URLWithString:[audioPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

AVAudioPlayer *AvAudioPlayer= [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:loadAudio error: nil];
[self setAudioPlayer:AvAudioPlayer ];

[self.AudioPlayer play];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(updateProgress)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
[self.AudioProgress setHidden:NO]; }
```

According to this code, all the paths are the same and I hear the same audio in all the elements. whether I'm reading index0 or 1 it is the same element! and that's not what I'm trying to do :(

any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change the name when you save then you are just overwriting the same file each time. So yes, all tracks in the array will play the same.

Consider creating a custom folder to save your audio in and using a time stamp or a UUID as the name for the files.